# Why is my already-defined global variable being overwritten by another var statement in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, global-variables

I have two script tags: one to set up my environment, and another to read that setup and act upon it. I've reduced the bug to the following:

```
<script>
    window.myVar = 'hello world';
</script>
<script>
    var myVar;
    console.log(window.myVar); // Should be 'hello world'
</script>
```

In IE9+, Chrome, etc. `'hello world'` gets logged. In IE8, however, `undefined` gets logged instead. What gives?

Comment: Why do you bother with the `var` statement? It's not needed for global variables.

Comment: @Barmar Only true if you include `window.` when you reference it. If you just said `alert(myVar);` without the `window.` and without declaring it or assigning it a value, it blows up.

Comment: do not redefine a global variable, this might lead to other issues. If you have to redefine it, use something like var myVar=myVar||''; in this case it will use the previously defined one or defines it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an obscure IE8 bug.

By simply putting all of the JS into a single script tag, you avoid the problem entirely. Not sure of a great workaround if you need them to be in separate script tags, but I'd love to hear one.

```
<!-- This triggers the bug in IE8. -->
<script>
    window.myVar = 'hello world';
</script>
<script>
    var myVar;
    console.log(window.myVar); // Should be 'hello world'
</script>


<!-- This does not trigger the bug in IE8. -->
<script>
    window.myOtherVar = 'hello world again';
    var myOtherVar;
    console.log(window.myOtherVar); // Should be 'hello world again'
</script>
```

[Here it is in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kerrick/pUNg6/show/). If you pull it up in IE8 with the F12 developer tools open, you'll see `undefined` and then `'hello world again'` logged.

Comment: This might be a bug but in general this is bad design of the code. You should not redefine global variables if they are already assigned, instead you want to use for example var myVar = myVar||'';
Because var myVar is also global, same as window.myVar...

Answer (score 0):

If these are both your scripts, why not define the variable (if you must define it twice) the same way both times?

```
<script>
 window.myVar = 'hello world';
</script>
<script>
 window.myVar = window.myVar || undefined;
 console.log(window.myVar); // Should be 'hello world'
</script>
```

Comment: The second script tag is generated via `grunt-contrib-requirejs` with the `namespace` option, so that my application only pollutes one global variable. I am not explicitly using `var` there, the `namespace` option does that.